# In hook_user_login is there a way to know if this is the first time the user has logged in?

Tags: 7, users

I'm overriding hook_user_login to redirect users to a specific page when they log in. The problem is I'm using the verification email setting on registration which requires the user to set their password on first login, but I redirect them so some users aren't able to login the 2nd time to the site.

Is there something I can check in hook_user_login that will tell me if this is the first time the user has logged into the site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a test on my test site, using the following code.

```
function code_testing_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  watchdog('code_testing', 'User name: %name, user access: %access, user login: %login', array('%name' => $account->name, '%access' => $account->access, '%login' => $account->login), WATCHDOG_DEBUG);
}
```

I then created a test user, and logged in with that account. The code I wrote output the following message:

> User name: test, user access: 0, user login: 1340038458

`$account->login` cannot be used because the user already logged in, when `hook_user_login()` is invoked. The only way to see if the user already logged in is to check `$account->access`.

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if ($account->access == 0) {
    // The user has never logged in before.
  }
}
```

Comment: I used if ($account->access > 0) { though as your if statement didn't seem to work

Comment: That is better; `$account->access` should never be negative, as it is a timestamp. If its value is bigger than `PHP_INT_MAX`, its value would be considered negative from PHP, though. (Integers in PHP are signed, and `PHP_INT_MAX` is the maximum positive value they can have.)

Comment: Drupal 8 version: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223410/45409

Answer (score 7):

Check for $account's access property. It is a timestemp the user logged in previously.

It should be other than a valid time stamp in case to be a first time login.

```
function MODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account){
debug($account->access);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but if I understand your scenario, this would help: don't do the redirect if the user logs in on the pass_reset page

```
function MYMODULE_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
    if (empty($_GET['destination'])) {
        if (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset') {

                drupal_goto('somewhere');
        }
    }
}
```