# Check if user is logged in first time

Tags: users

How can i check if user is logged in for the first time on site?

If it is, i want to show him a message...

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In both Drupal 7 and 8, there is hook_user_login, where you can can check whether the current user has accessed the site before, but the parameters are slightly different.

Drupal 7 version:

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if ($account->access == 0) {
    drupal_set_message(t('This is your first login. Welcome!'));
  }
}
```

Drupal 8 version:

```
function mymodule_user_login($account) {
  if (!$account->getLastAccessedTime()) {
    drupal_set_message(t('This is your first login. Welcome!'));
  }
}
```

[hook_user_login](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/8.2.x) in Drupal 8.

Comment: This works sometimes, depending on your situation. The Masquerade module, for one, updates the access value for a user account separately from login. hook_user_login runs after the login value has been updated from 0 to a timestamp. I am hoping to find another way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

** UPDATE **

As suggested by oknate, using hook_user_login:

```
function hook_user_login(&$edit, $account)
{
  if(!$account->access)
  {
    drupal_set_message(t('This is your first login. Welcome!'));
  }
}
```

** Original less optimal method **

You can use hook_init() in D7, and check if they have a value for last access:

```
function hook_init()
{
  global $user;

  $first_login = db_query('SELECT 1 FROM {users} WHERE uid = :uid AND access = 0', array(':uid' => $user->uid))->fetchField();

  if($first_login)
  {
    drupal_set_message(t('This is your first login. Welcome!'));
  }
}
```

Comment: hook_init runs on every uncached page load.  I would suggest finding another way.

Comment: There are ways you can minimize it - such as adding a field to the {users} table and flagging in on first login. This would be automatically loaded with the user object for every page load, not requiring the additional query shown here. But I don't see any other way you could do it without checking on every page load. Suggestions?

Comment: look into hook_user_login, and the $user->access flag on the user.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.

Comment: then $account->access, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34397/in-hook-user-login-is-there-a-way-to-know-if-this-is-the-first-time-the-user-has

Answer (score 1):

For D7 you can use rules to achieve the same,

Here is the sample rule,

```
{ "rules_first_login_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "First login test",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "user" : { "label" : "User", "type" : "user" } },
    "IF" : [ { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "user:last-access" ] } } ],
    "DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "True" } } ]
  }
}
```

Import this rule and modify according to your need.

You can check the more information [here](http://drupal.org/node/1079018#comment-6417862).