# Is there any way to know if it is the first visit of a Anonymous User?

Tags: 7

I'd like to know if is there any way to know if it is the first visit of a Anonymous User?

If so, can I fire up a rule to redirect the visitor to other page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In hook\_user\_login is there a way to know if this is the first time the user has logged in?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34397/in-hook-user-login-is-there-a-way-to-know-if-this-is-the-first-time-the-user-has)

Comment: @NikhilM That is for authenticated user, this question as it is, includes anonymous as well.

Comment: @chefnelone Its really hard to track anonymous users first visit, simplest way is to test for a cookie, if its not there its his first visit and then you drop a cookie. But this logic will fail if user cleared cookies.

Comment: @2-Stroker: I think you are right, a cookie would be the only way to do this. Any module to create cookie? Do I need to create the cookie programmatically?

Comment: A module would be a overkill for such a simple task, unless you already have one custom module you can use that. Else use your theme files. And yes you need to create it programmatically

Comment: @2-Stroker thanks, do you mind to move your comments as a answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @2-Stroker why would you do this at the theme layer? What happens when they switch themes? This definitely belongs in a module.

Comment: @AdamBalsam I Agree it belongs in a module, but adding one module just to set a cookie is an overkill. It will try to call all possible hooks in new module.

Comment: @2-Stroker At the risk of sounding like I'm arguing with you after you said, "I agree" - Additional modules are a negligible performance hit. "[due to a PHP quirk (it keeps an internal hashtable of all loaded functions), it allows Drupal to quickly check for listeners just by iterating over a list of installed plugins.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068556/how-drupal-works)" And, in theory, this module could do much more. I could even see there being a case for this as a contrib module that integrates with the rules module.

Comment: Looks like somebody has taken a stab at this already: http://drupal.org/sandbox/johnnygamba/1851384. I don't see the need for any js and I would add an admin page where you can set the cookie length. But it's a start.

Comment: @2-Stroker when i posted the answer the question was like this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/66946/1

Comment: If you’re willing to work with cache, try also working with “local storage”. This is a browser variable you can access easily with JavaScript. Both cache and local storage can be destroyed by the user via browser settings, but that’s the way it’s supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set a cookie when folks visit, then you can check for whether they have the cookie. No cookie = first time visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way;

In the Global [$user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) check for `access` if its set to 0, the user is never logged in to the site.

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if ($account->access == 0) {
    // The user has never logged in before.
  }
}
```

**When i posted the answer the question was like this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/66946/1**

Comment: but this is for authenticated user. I need it for anonymous users. I think that the only way way is a cookie.

Comment: This wont work for anonymous users

Comment: @2-Stroker when i posted the answer the question was like this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/66946/1

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by inserting cookies in the user's browser.
After that check, it has cookies or not and do your further things.
:)