# Check, anywhere during a session, if a logged in user has previously logged in

Tags: 7, users, sessions

There are a number of properties on the global $user object
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/user/7

But I can't figure out how to see if a logged in user has ever previously logged in, or if this is his/her first session. When logged in, the $user->access, $user->login, $user->timestamp values all seem to point of the current session.

I can set a cookie and check for that cookie myself. But I suspect I'm just missing something Drupal already has ?

Comment: $user->access should work for you. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34397/in-hook-user-login-is-there-a-way-to-know-if-this-is-the-first-time-the-user-has

Comment: good find @arpitr this question could qualify as a duplicate of 34397

Comment: $user->access seems set to the current login here, not the previous. perhaps that's not true on hook_user_login, but it seems to be so in subsequent requests ?

Comment: in the subsequent requests it will set to timestamp when accessed, but not will be 0

Comment: exactly. so its not a duplicate of 34397

Answer (score 1):

A cookie would work. Another way is to add a field to the user entity that you can check that field first to see if it's empty, and then modify it with a Rule, triggered by the log in action